# How to convert sbt.InputTask[T] to sbt.Task[T]?

Tags: scala, sbt

How can I convert `sbt.InputTask[T]` to `sbt.Task[T]`?

I know that this is possible in 0.13.5 using `toTask` method. Sadly, in our project we use v0.13.0.

Comment: Have you tried using the source code from 0.13.5: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/main/settings/src/main/scala/sbt/InputTask.scala#L27

Comment: I saw this code and decided to ask this question. I didn't want to risk losing a few more hours trying to understand what's actually going on there.